# How to load the xml file from webpage and read particular nodes from xml?

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I am planning to load below mentioned xml from the webpage and then want to read particular nodes from it.Filtering condition: if "displayname" attribute contains "isc-asr901a"it should pick the first node and return the attribute "id" value of node ethernetProtocolEndpointExtendedDTO"

```
<queryResponse type="EthernetProtocolEndpoint">
<entity >
<ethernetProtocolEndpointExtendedDTO id="2283315" displayName="4c2b8aa7[2275273_isc-      asr901a,GigabitEthernet0/0]">
<name>GigabitEthernet0/0</name>
<adminStatus>UP</adminStatus>
</ethernetProtocolEndpointExtendedDTO>
</entity>
<entity >
<ethernetProtocolEndpointExtendedDTO id="2283315" displayName="4c2b8aa7[2275273_isc-asr901a,GigabitEthernet0/0]">
<name>GigabitEthernet0/0</name>
<adminStatus>UP</adminStatus>
</ethernetProtocolEndpointExtendedDTO>
</entity>
</queryResponse>
```

I am planning to do this using ruby. but I am new to ruby. Could someone help me to perform this. by using which parser i can do it easily?  I am using below code to perform this but code is not returning any value.

```
strurl = "https://.."
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(strurl))  
doc.xpath('//queryResponse/entity/ethernetProtocolEndpointDTO[@displayName="[^"]*isc-asr901a[^"]*]').each do |node|          
puts node['id']
end
```

Thanks,
Chandana

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Nokogiri::XML`, not `Nokogiri::HTML`, since this is an XML. Furthermore, you had a typo in `ethernetProtocolEndpointExtendedDTO` - you wrote `ethernetProtocolEndpointDTO`.

Also, you should use [`contains`](http://www.abodeqa.com/2013/01/29/contains-and-starts-with-function-in-xpath/) to find the display names which contain your string:

```
strurl = "https://.."
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(strurl))  
doc.xpath('//queryResponse/entity/ethernetProtocolEndpointExtendedDTO[contains(@displayName, "isc-asr901a")]').each do |node|          
  puts node['id']
end
# => 2283315
```